# Asymptotics of orthonormal basis in $\ell^2$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, asymptotics, compact-operators

Is it true that for all orthognal basis $\{e_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ of  $\ell^2(\mathbb N)$, we have
$$\sup_{n}n^2 \sum_{k=1}^\infty  (e_n(k))^2 k^{-2}<\infty? $$

where $e_n=(e_n(1),e_n(2),\cdots,e_n(k),\cdots)\in \ell^2(\mathbb N)$ and
$$ \langle e_n,e_m \rangle_{\ell^2}=\sum_{k=1}^\infty e_n(k)e_m(k)=\delta(m,n).$$

For the special case: the standard orthognal basis $\bar {e_n}(k)=\delta(k,n),$ it's clearly true
$$ n^2 \sum_{k=1}^\infty  (\bar {e_n}(k))^2 k^{-2}=1,\quad \text{for all $n$.}$$
For general orthognal basis, I think it's not true, but I can't find a counter example.

Update: At first I thought this argument is far too strong, construct some other ONB and reorder them would make a counterexample, but I'm not so sure about it now. Note this truth, define $T\in \mathscr L(\ell (\mathbb N))$:
$$T(\bar{e_n})=n^{-1}\bar {e_n},$$
it's straightforward that $T$ is a Hilbert–Schmidt operator:
$$\|T\|^2_{HS}=\sum_n \|T({e_n})\|^2=\sum_n \|T(\bar{e_n})\|^2=\sum_n n^{-2}<\infty. $$
Note that the asymptotic above is
$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty  (e_n(k))^2 k^{-2}=\|T({e_n})\|^2,$$
and the question turns to
$$\|T({e_n})\|=O(n^{-1})?$$
That is, is the "tail" of the Hilbert–Schmidt norm of $T$ decrease in the same speed no matter what ONB we choose?

Comment: Have you tried the standard orthonormal basis $e_n(k) = \delta(n,k)$?

Comment: The standard basis gives the value $n^2\sum_k e_n^2(k)k^{-2}=1$

Comment: What do you mean by $e^2(k)$? Note that $e(k)$ is a vector, how do you take a power from that ?

Comment: Sorry for the notation, might cause some misunderstanding. $e_n\in\ell^2$ means $e_n=(e_n(1),e_n(2),\cdots,e_n(k),\cdots)\in \ell^2$.

Comment: Ok, so $\sup_n 1 < \infty$, what's the problem?

Comment: My bad, my question is that, is it always true for all orthogonal basis of $\ell^2$ that $\sup _n n^2 \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\left(e_n(k)\right)^2 k^{-2}<\infty$. For standard basis, the answer is yes, but for general basis, the argument seems to be too strong, but I can't find a counterexample...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is false in general. Start by constructing a bijective $\varphi$ from $\mathbb N$ to $\mathbb N$ such that $\varphi\left(n^4\right) = n^2$. This should not be difficult since $\mathbb N\backslash \left\{n^4: n\in \mathbb N\right\}$ and $\mathbb N\backslash \left\{n^2: n\in \mathbb N\right\}$ are both infinite countable sets. Now let $e_n = \overline e_{\varphi(n)}$. For every $n$,

$$n^8 \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} e_{n^4}(k)k^{-2} = n^8 \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \overline e_{\varphi\left(n^4\right)}(k)k^{-2} = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \overline e_{n^2}(k)k^{-2} = n^{8} \left(n^{2}\right)^{-2} = n^4 \to \infty$$

Comment: You are right, that is, by rearrange, the converging rate can be arbitrarily slow.

Answer (score -1):

I guess you can do the following, let
$$v=\frac{\sqrt6}{\pi}(1,\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{3},\ldots)$$
then $v$ is a unit vector.

Now take an ONB that contains $v$, such system exists since we can e.g., replace $e_0$ with $v$ in the standard ONB, and apply a Gram-Schmidt procedure.

Next we rearrange this ONB, so that after $n$-th re-ordering $v$ appears as the $n$-th basis vector, then the sup in OP is at least $$n^2\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}v_k^2k^{-2}=n^2\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}k^{-4}=\frac{n^2\pi^4}{90}\to\infty$$

Comment: I don't think this will work, since finitely many "bad" unit vector won't change the asymptotic. For any given order of your example, the asymptotic remains unchanged I guess.